# how to write delete record confermation

Tags: php, html

i write a class for work with database. this class has many function like delete,login,insert,update and... and this class working fine and don't problem.
i want write a code for delete a record
this is my code:

```
 ///// Delete A record
    elseif($_GET['act']=='del'){
        require_once '../classes/user.class.php';
        $us=new User();
        $us->user_id=$_GET['id'];
    ?>
    do you want delete this username?
    <br>
    <a href="user_management.php?action=delyes&id=<?phpecho$us->user_id;?>">yes</a>
    <a href="user_management.php?action=delno">دخ</a>
    <?php
    if ($_GET['action']=="delyes"){
    $us->Delete();
    echo "complete";
        }elseif ($_GET['action']=="delno"){
    echo "you cansle it";
    }
    }
```

please help, and i remember function delete work correctly and my confirmation code has problem.
thanks.

Comment: You might want to give us your user.class.php or the code for deleting a user.

Comment: Javascript confirm() may help you

Comment: <a href="user_management.php?action=delyes&id=<?php echo $us->user_id;?>" onclick="return confirm('Aru You Delete Sure')";>>[Yes]</a>

Comment: It's difficult to understand what your desired behaviour is.  Can you clarify?

Comment: hi. my php code has a problem for run. this code has not error but not work. my html code is correct. my delete query is   $query="delete from users 
  where user_id='".$this->user_id."'";
and i remember my query doesn't problem. please help

Comment: if you can please help me.